# Uniform convergence on subintervals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

I have just started learning pointwise convergence and uniform convergence, and I am facing some confusion between two statements.

1. (Proven to be true) Let $f_n : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions which converges pointwise to a limit $f:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$. This implies that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on {$\text{$1,...,N$}$} for any N $\epsilon$ $\Bbb{N}$

Now I have another statement:

2. Let M be a fixed positive integer M and let ${f_n:[0,M] \to \Bbb{R}}$ be a sequence of functions. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[0,M]$ and that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on each subinterval $[k-1,k]$ for each $k=1,...,M$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,M]$.

I cannot figure out how the condition of uniform convergence on subintervals changes the question. Doesn't the first statement proves the second statement? Hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I now have an idea the difference between these two statements. Can anybody guide me on proving the second statement then?

Edit: I constructed a proof for the second statement:

By assumption, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N_k(\varepsilon)$ such that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \varepsilon$$ for all $n \ge N_k(\varepsilon)$

We choose $N^*(\varepsilon)=\max\{N_1,...,N_{M-1}\}$.

Hence, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N^*(\varepsilon)$ such that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in[0,M]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$ $$=\max\{\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|,...,\sup_{x\in[M-1,M]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\}$$ $=\varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N^*(\varepsilon)$

We conclude that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,M]$

Is this proof logical?

Comment: No, the first statement does not prove the second. The functions in your first proposition have a domain of $\mathbb{N}$. The functions in your second proposition have domains that are subintervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since M can be any integer, doesn't it represent the domain of $\Bbb{N}$ ?

Comment: The first says that $f_n(k) \to f(k)$ for each $k$, hence for any finite $K$, $f_n \to f$ 'uniformly' on $K$. It is not really saying very much. However, if $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, then it is still true that $f_n \to f$ on any finite $T \subset [0,1]$, but it doesn't follow that the convergence in uniform for any infinite subset $T \subset [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement does not prove the second. Take $f_n(x)=x^n$ then it converges uniformly in $\{0,1\}$ but it does not converge uniformly in $[0,1]$.

As regards a proof of the first and the second statement, basically we use the same fact: if we have uniform convergence in $A$ and in $B$ then we have uniform convergence in $A\cup B$ (which implies that we can take the union of any finite number of sets). This follows from the property:
$$\sup_{x\in A\cup B}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\max\left(\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|, \sup_{x\in B}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! I somehow got the difference between these two statements. Can I then have some hint about how to prove the second statement? Is it to treat each subinterval [k-1,k] as in the first statement?

Comment: @javabeginner_0101 Yes, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance!

Comment: I constructed a proof in my edited question, could you help me see whether it makes sense?

Comment: @javabeginner_0101 Yes, it works!